# jquery need to delay call to plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jmenu

I'm injecting the HTML for web page's header into the DOM via jquery (simulate a masterpage).  In the header I load a jquery navigation menu plugin called [jMenu](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jMenu).  I am able to inject the HTML for the header and it appears no problem.  After that loads, I need to make the jquery call to jMenu.

The problem is it looks like the jMenu call is being made before the DOM is finished updating and throws an error complaining it can't find one of the html elements.  So I tried to delay loading to jMenu but I don't think the call is even getting executed now since my alerts aren't popping up.  I've done some searching on this already but have not been able to get this to work.  I'm guessing its a minor syntax thing.  I tried a few things:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="mpheader"> 
    <div class="header"> <!-- start of injected html -->
    <br/><br/>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Reports</h1>
    <div class="centerControl">
        <ul id="jMenu">
        ...
    </div>               <!-- end of injected html -->
</div>

<div class="content">

    <h2>Welcome</h2>
    ...
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Load Header
$.get( 
    "./header.jsp", 
    function(data) {
        $(".mpheader").html(data); 
    }
);

// Initialize Navigation Menu
$(".header").on("load", function() { /* doesn't get called */
    alert('called');
    $("#jMenu").jMenu();
})

$(".mpheader").on("load", function() { /* doesn't get called */
    alert('called');
    $("#jMenu").jMenu();
})

$(window).load(function(){   /* doesn't get called */
    alert('called');
    $("#jMenu").jMenu();        
})

//$("#jMenu").jMenu(); /* will cause error complaining about dom */

// TODO: Load Footer

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once your get returns, you are calling a function to fill the html of your header. You can just setup the menu after that. The following should work for you:

```
$.get("./header.jsp", 
    function(data) {
        $(".mpheader").html(data);
        $("#jMenu").jMenu(); 
    }
);
```

Comment: Okay that worked.  So conceptually in my above example, does the $.get get called asynch and then the $("jmenu") gets called right after it? Putting them inside a single javascript function changes the behavior to have them be ran synchronously instead?

Comment: No - the second parameter to `$.get()` is a `success` handler. It's an event which receives 3 parameters whenever the function succeeds - the first of which is the data being received. You are capturing that by having a function argument called `data`. Essentially, your `$.get()` call fires, and unless the server throws an error such as a 404 code, your `function(data)` gets called - and continues the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Load Header
    $.get( 
        "./header.jsp", 
        function(data) {
            $(".mpheader").html(data).trigger('loaded'); // Fire a custom event.
        }
    );

    // Initialize Navigation Menu - occurs when your custom event is fired.
    $(".mpheader").on("loaded", function() {
        $("#jMenu").jMenu();
    });
});
```

Because in this approach you are creating an event-sequence, the event is only fired after your AJAX call completes, and loads your menu items.

Comment: Ah okay.  I have to manually fire the loaded event to do it the way I was trying to do.  I figured the event was fired automatically after the mpheader was done updating.  Seems like kind of strange logic to me personally.

Comment: It's not that there is an event which you have to fire manually - it's that there is no event. A DOM object doesn't raise a "load" event when it is added to the page by default - so your menu doesn't do so. However, you can easily cause it to do so - as demonstrated in the example - by firing a custom event. Ignore the fact that it is called `loaded` in the example - you could just as easily call it `foo`, and it would still work.